Stylus Button keeps printing last highlighted text after installing xbindkeys
I use a Fujitsu Lifebook tablet PC with an integrated stylus and just installed arch on it with i3 as a window manager. To still have access to the Super key while in tablet mode i tried to map the stylus build in button as Super. I tried to follow the archwiki instruction but as soon as I installed xbindkeys my stylus key started to behave strangely. When pressed it prints the last selected string in my system as if it were a macro key. According to xev this is the profile of the button
ButtonPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
root 0x5a9, subw 0x0, time 22127626, (314,506), root:(959,554),
state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES

On the other hand in the sample .xbindkeysrc that is requiered to run xbindkeys there is this showcase line :
"xterm"
   controle + b:2

I tried to modify the rc file, relaunch xbindkeys, reboot my pc even completly reinstall the package but the problem stays even without xbindkeys active or even installed.
